# How does checking for CNF satisfiability by going via DNF compare to using a truth table or DPLL?

Tags: propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

In terms of efficiency, I know DPLL would be most efficient, and probably going via a DNF would be least efficient, but my question is asking for reasons why and trying to understand by **how much**?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the computer science site more than it is a question for the mathematics website.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila, I will consider moving it, I wasn't too concerned with computer efficiency, more mathematical efficiency, for example I know DNF formulas grow exponentially so would be inefficient, but i'm not sure about the others.

Comment: I'm not sure what "mathematical efficiency" means. Growth rate is a concern of both mathematicians and computer scientists. So if you clarify what you mean, it might be more suitable here after all, or it might be clearer that it's better posted there instead.